# Mensagem aparecer quando selecionar valor em um dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Crei um dropdownlist em asp.net vinculado a um banco de dados. Agora eu quero que uma mensagem apareça assim que um dos valores do db for selecionado.

(Ex: Um dropdownlist com tres valores "A", "B", "C". Quando eu clico em "B", uma mensagem aparece dizendo: "Você escolheu B).

Segue código

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult dbExample()
    {
        copaDBEntities entity = new copaDBEntities();
        var getCopaList = entity.copa.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getCopaList, "id", "ano");
        ViewBag.copalistano = list;

        return View();
    }
}
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "dbExample";
}

<h2>Copa do Mundo</h2>

@Html.DropDownList("CopaList", ViewBag.copalistano as SelectList, "Selecione o ano")
```

Answer (score 0):

Se deseja exibir uma uma mensagem na tela para o usuário informando qual item ele escolheu, não há necessidade de novamente realizar interação com o banco de dados. o exemplo a seguir será apenas com `javascript`

Primeiro, adicione no local desejado um elemento `span` com um `id`,

```
<span id="msg"></span>
```

Após isso, na área de `scripts`, adicione o seguinte código

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
    function exibeMensagemItemSelecionado(){
            myDropDown = document.getElementById("CopaList")
            document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = "Você escolheu a opção "+  myDropDown.options[myDropDown.selectedIndex].text
        } 
</script>
```

Altere o seu `DropDownList` adicionando a `function` no evento `change` dele

```
@Html.DropDownList("CopaList", (SelectList)ViewBag.Anos, "Selecione o ano", new { @onchange="exibeMensagemItemSelecionado()"})
```

**Explicação:**

Foi adicionado no evento ´change`do seu`DropDownList`uma`function`, nessa`function`pegamos o elemento`span`e atribuímos o texto desejado mais o texto selecionado do`DropDownList`. o`DropDownList`irá ter o`ID`**CopaList**, pois é o primeiro parâmetro passado no`DropDownList`

Deixei o código(Atualizado) no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u5B5Nd)

Comment: Ainda não funciona, não pensei em usar jquery e não achei como colocar o id no select

Comment: @bcastro1995, coloca na pergunta o código da sua `View`, por favor, após isso vou editar a pergunto com `javascript` apenas

Comment: @bcastro1995 atualizei com javascript